# In Java, how would I round a number to an arbitrary level of precision?

Tags: java, rounding

For example suppose I have a method

```
double roundDown(double unrounded, double precision) {
}

roundDown(137.42973, 0.01) would return 137.42
roundDown(137.42973, 0.05) would return 137.4
roundDown(137.42973, 0.25) would return 137.25
```

Are there libraries to do something like this otherwise is the algorithm reasonably simple?

Comment: Could you use BigDecimal instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the original number by the precision, round down to the nearest integer, and then multiply by the precision again:

```
double roundDown(double unrounded, double precision) {
    return precision * Math.floor(unrounded / precision);
}
```

Note that inherent floating point inaccuracies mean that your number may not be *exactly* the answer you're looking for - e.g. you might get 137.399999 instead of 137.4

Comment: +1: Perhaps `Math.round()` is a better function for rounding. ;) You can reduce the rounding error by using 100 instead of 0.01 as this can be represented exactly. (and swapping / and *)

Comment: @Peter he did specifically say round _down_.   Good point on using the reciprocal of the precision, but then his API would have to change too.

Answer (score 4):

If you want *truly* arbitrary precision in decimal, look into this library: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: not getting a +1 from me without sample code (and an up-to-date reference!)